# I just cant see why edittext does not appear on checking a radio button

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this XML which i using for my Java activity in Android. I want the contact number edittext to become visible when user selects female as a gender but it stays invisible when male is selected.

Code is in its primary stage but I want this functionality to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"

        >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/contact"
        android:inputType="phone" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" 
        android:hint="@string/entername"     >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="251dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enteruser" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/age" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/pswrd" />

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/male" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/female" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am trying to use this XML and make the contact number visible only when     female radio button is selected.

Java file is:

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity  implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{


    private RadioGroup radioGroup1; 
    private EditText et;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.registration);

         radioGroup1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
         //test listening to radio group 
         radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
         et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            }

     public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
         if(checkedId == R.id.radio1){
            et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
     }
```

Comment: You are changing the visibility of editText5, while editText3 is set to invisible in xml

Comment: your edittext5 is visible from start ..

Answer (score 1):

You call

```
et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
```

but editText5 is visible in your XML Layout , i.e.,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="258dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/age" />
```

So please call the invisible editText3 and I think then it will work for you. So replace your code

```
et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
```

by this one

```
 et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

your editText3 is

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="252dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/contact"
    android:inputType="phone" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little funny.

Your edittext3 is invisible and edittext5 is visible form start.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="252dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/contact"
    android:inputType="phone" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

In your code you try to visible edittext5 which is already visible.

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
     if(checkedId == R.id.radio1){
        et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
 }
```

Just change `et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);` to `et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);`

Good programmings.. :)

Comment: my bad..it is never easy to spon ur own mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the wrong edittext id in onCreate. The phone edittext is 3. Hope it helps.